# CASE WHEN THEN resolving to zeros in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite inside my .NET application and I have the following query:

```
select (CASE IFNULL(CCODE_1, '') when 'STD' then '_' else '' end) + 
(CASE IFNULL(CFRRR_CS, '') when '1' then 'F_' when '2' then 'R_' when '3' then 'FR_' else '' end) + 
IFNULL(CCODE_1, '') +
(CASE when (IFNULL(CCODE_2, '') = '') then '' else '_' end) + 
IFNULL(CCODE_2, '') +
(CASE when (IFNULL(CCODE_3, '') = '') then '' else '_' end) + 
IFNULL(CCODE_3, '') as OptionID
from X20_TIRES
```

The query above produces a single `OptionID` column of all 0s. Nothing else.

And here is some sample data from X20_TIRES:

[image]

I am expecting results such as the following:

```
R_F41A
R_F41V
etc...
```

It's clear to me that the `case/when/then` is breaking down and simply spitting out 0s, but I cannot understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate all these results from the CASE statements, 
you must use the `||` operator instead of `+`:

```
select 
  (CASE IFNULL(CCODE_1, '') when 'STD' then '_' else '' end) || 
(CASE IFNULL(CFRRR_CS, '') when '1' then 'F_' when '2' then 'R_' when '3' then 'FR_' else '' end) || 
IFNULL(CCODE_1, '') ||
(CASE when (IFNULL(CCODE_2, '') = '') then '' else '_' end) || 
IFNULL(CCODE_2, '') ||
(CASE when (IFNULL(CCODE_3, '') = '') then '' else '_' end) || 
IFNULL(CCODE_3, '') as OptionID
from X20_TIRES
```